# How to override updateSegmentRequestInfo for custom receiver?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I do not understand how it works in this context.The function I have used to override is not being called. Instead the default one is used.
Could someone give an example as to how to properly override **`updateSegmentRequestInfo()`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var host = new cast.player.api.Host({'mediaElement':mediaElement, 'url':url});
host.updateSegmentRequestInfo = function(requestInfo) {
  // example of setting CORS withCredentials
  requestInfo.withCredentials = true;
  // example of setting headers
  requestInfo.headers = {};
  requestInfo.headers['content-type'] = 'text/xml;charset=utf-8';
};
```

Comment: But it isn't getting intercepted for my HLS video with extension `.m3u8`. Any thoughts?